# Stack Overflow due to array size in c

Tags: c, visual-studio, exception, stack-overflow

In a function that reads some log file line by line,
there is an array, declared like this:

```
arrays[process][lines][line size]
```

number of lines in log file does not exceed (process * lines).
each line in that file does not exceed (line size) length.

If it reads one small file, for examle 30kb, the program runs well,
hovewer, when it reads larger file, with 80kb,
the program throws stack overflow exception even before main.
So it looks like this:

```
char arrays[150][2][2048] // ok, with 30kb file
char arrays[500][2][2048] // stack overflow exception, with 80kb file
```

Why does that exception happens ?

PS: i'm using visual studio 2013, language is C

Comment: what's the data type of `arrays`, BTW?

Comment: @SouravGhosh, it's char. corrected

Comment: Dynamic allocation of your arrays is probably the correct solution.

Comment: @MohitJain, it's in C

Comment: Then why did you tag this as C++? Also, C can allocate buffers too, you know.

Comment: @YaroslavAlexeevich 1. if you know its `c`, why'd you tag `c++`? 2. what does dynamic allocation has to do with `c` or `c++`, anyway? HInt: `malloc()`, `free()`.....

Comment: I didn't expect such fast responses, just wanted to cover larger audience.